# What is Causing this Unwanted Content Inset with UITextView in iOS 8 (not there in iOS 7)?

Tags: ios7, uitextview, ios8, nslayoutmanager, nstextcontainer

I've been creating `UITextView`s programatically, using auto layout, in iOS 7. Something like this:

```
_textView = [UITextView new];
_textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0];
_textView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_textView];
```

In addition to the other constraints I've created, I have *this one* for the bottom of the text view:

```
_textViewBottomConstraint = 
       [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_textView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                      constant:0.0];

[self.view addConstraint:_textViewBottomConstraint];
```

So that I can change the constraint when the keyboard shows:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)sender
{
    CGRect keyboardFrame = 
                        [sender.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect convertedFrame = 
                        [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:self.view.window];
    _textViewBottomConstraint.constant = -convertedFrame.size.height;
    [_textView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

That's all been working fine...

#### Problem

I've just switched over to Xcode 6 and iOS 8 (late, I know) - and the text within the `UITextView` now has an inset at the top. E.g. (Text view background is yellow):

[image]

What's causing the inset? Is it connected to `NSTextContainer` and `textContainerInset`?

- Is working with `NSTextContainer` and `textContainerInset` the *correct* way to use `UITextView` from iOS 7 and onward?
- Does it **have** to be done that way in iOS 8?

If yes, I'd appreciate some guidance for programatically creating a `UITextView` along with the necessary `NSTextContainer` and `NSLayoutManager`; then setting `textContainerInset`. (I'll be using auto layout, programatically).

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets works a bit differently in iOS 8. In 7, it only applied if the controller's view property was a scrollView. In 8, it seems to apply to scroll views that are subviews of the controllers' view.

Answer (score 7):

It's the `contentInset` from the `UIViewController`.

It seems that with iOS 8, with my `UITextView` as it is within my `UIViewController`, there's a need to explicitly set:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Without explicitly setting that, I've checked the difference between a physical iPhone 5s running iOS 7 and the Simulator iPhone 5s running iOS 8.

Here is some log output, checking the top value for `textContainerInset`, `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInset`. In each case, after `viewDidLoad` and `keyboardDidShow`.

**iPhone 5s Device running iOS 7**:

```
2014-09-12 07:55:01.244 Alter[19147:60b] viewDidLoad
2014-09-12 07:55:01.249 Alter[19147:60b] textContainerInset Top: 8.000000
2014-09-12 07:55:01.252 Alter[19147:60b] contentInset Top: 0.000000
2014-09-12 07:55:01.253 Alter[19147:60b] scrollIndicatorInset Top: 0.000000

2014-09-12 07:55:02.515 Alter[19147:60b] keyboardDidShow
2014-09-12 07:55:02.516 Alter[19147:60b] textContainerInset Top: 8.000000
2014-09-12 07:55:02.516 Alter[19147:60b] contentInset Top: 0.000000
2014-09-12 07:55:02.516 Alter[19147:60b] scrollIndicatorInset Top: 0.000000
```

**Simulator iPhone 5s (or 6, or 6 Plus) running iOS 8**:

```
2014-09-12 07:55:39.395 Alter[2120:109535] viewDidLoad
2014-09-12 07:55:39.395 Alter[2120:109535] textContainerInset Top: 8.000000
2014-09-12 07:55:39.396 Alter[2120:109535] contentInset Top: 0.000000
2014-09-12 07:55:39.396 Alter[2120:109535] scrollIndicatorInset Top: 0.000000

2014-09-12 07:55:39.939 Alter[2120:109535] keyboardDidShow
2014-09-12 07:55:39.939 Alter[2120:109535] textContainerInset Top: 8.000000
2014-09-12 07:55:39.939 Alter[2120:109535] contentInset Top: 64.000000
2014-09-12 07:55:39.939 Alter[2120:109535] scrollIndicatorInset Top: 64.000000
```

To answer my own question, I don't **need** to manually set up the `NSTextContainer` and the `NSLayoutManager`. Though it might be better to start using the `textContainerInset` approach, I have the option to adjust the frame if I set this in the parent view controller:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```